# How to add correct citing of figures?

Tags: floats, citing, licensing

Let's say I have a figure environment like this:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth] {figure}
\caption{My Caption ... }
\label{fig:figure}
\end{figure}
```

What is the correct way to cite the author and License of this figure? Let's say I use an image from Wikimedia Commons from author xyz with licence "Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported". Is the only way to add this information to \caption? For example: `\caption{My Caption ...; Author of image: xyz, Source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/.../..., Licence: Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported}`

Comment: Can you please use an example-image from the `graphicx` packages instead of figure? Can you please add the missing parts so it compiles when we copied it? (For a step-by-step procedure kindly have a look here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790) . Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `copyrightbox` package. Here is a simple example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond, cabin}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption, copyrightbox}
\captionsetup{justification=centering, labelfont=sc, labelsep=endash}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[!h]
  \centering
  \copyrightbox[r]{\includegraphics[scale = 1.1]{Piero_di_Cosimo_3}}{\textcopyright Piero di Cosimo\\Musée Condé }
  \caption{Portrait of Simonetta Vespucci (ca 1480),\\\textit{Piero di Cosimo}}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]