# How do you put a reference next to image?

Tags: graphics, annotations

I want to put a refererence next to image, for example: I want to put the word enclosed in red: 
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drawing on an image with TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz)

Comment: Much more simply, you have the `copyrightbox` package. Please see my answer to a [similar post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236605/how-do-correct-citing-of-figures/236616#236616).

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways to do this.

Note: `\llap` does not automatically start a new paragraph, hence the `\leavevmode`.  It may not be obvious, but the minipage is indented (by `\parindent`).

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-\parindent}
\leavevmode\llap{\rotatebox{90}{\strut Bogus Name}}%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}\par
\textsf{\Large\strut Example Image}\par
(from MWE package)
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

This is easier to set up:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{r@{\hspace{2pt}}l}
\rotatebox{90}{Bogus Name} & \includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image}\\
 & \textsf{\Large Example Image}\\
 & (from MWE package)
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```